# Hadoop Mapreduce JSON object with members to .txt

Tags: java, json, hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop newbie here...

I'm writing a mapreduce algorithm. As input, I got a JSON with members. [Input JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fc44L.png)
A member can vote on a song. I need the summation of how much votes are given to a song in a rave `("rave_id")`
A vote can be +1 or -1, represented by the `"preference"` boolean: true = +1, false = -1.

I need the output for the mapreduce to be a `.txt` file in this format.

```
"rave_ID_X" "song_ID_1" "Count_1"
"rave_ID_X" "song_ID_2" "Count_1"
"rave_ID_x" "song_ID_3" "Count_1"
```

**How can I iterate over all the members of the input JSON object?** 
My first thought is to use as key the "rave_id"+"song_ID" and as value the preference boolean?

Then in the `reduce` method i can use this logic to reduce the booleans to vote counts.

```
 int sum = 0;
        for ( String val: values){
            if (val == "true"){
                sum +=1;
            }
            else if (val == "false"){
                sum -=1;
            }
        }
```

But, **how can I output this in a `.txt` file, instead of a json**?

Many thanks in advance!